# Microsoft Edge Keeps Prompting For Certificate

Tags: internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge, client-certificates

I have an application that uses certificates (*.p12) to authenticate users. I want to be able to use it in Microsoft Edge (version 42) and Internet Explorer (version 11), but these browsers give me issues.

Speaking specifically of Edge, I have added the certificates to the certificate store, and they are available for me to login. When I navigate to the website, I get prompted with a window that says "Select a Certificate" (as I expect) and I select the desired user's certificate from the prompts dropdown and click "OK".

This is where the issue occurs. After I select the certificate, the prompt immediately pops back up. The prompt can reappear between 2 and 10 times. It seems to be worse in Internet Explorer. Either way, the re-prompt impacts my ability to do a number of things with the website that I need to do.

Is this a common issue? Is there something that I ought to change in my browser settings in order to prevent it?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Check the certificate make sure it is available and not expired. Then, you can try to clear the browser cache and history, then restart the Browser to open the page. If still not working, try to [reset the Browser settings](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/reset-microsoft-edge-browser-to-default-settings-in-windows-10).

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, it appears to be something else.

The certificate and issuer say: "Valid from 12/29/2017 to 12/30/2027"

Clearing the cache doesn't do it, either, because I do that every time I switch users. (The application has multiple users, each with their own certificate.)

Internet Explorer seems to lack the reset option, though the original settings caused the same problem. It was like this out of the box. When anyone, with any IE instance, accesses the site, they get this problem. Multiple certificate prompts. It takes 5 or 6 authentications before it is done.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I've faced the same problem.

**Solution 1**

Create a DWORD item `ForceCertificatePromptsOnMultipleMatches` with value `0` in registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Edge`

**Solution 2**

Create a string value in `SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge\AutoSelectCertificateForUrls`

Value Name: `1`, `2`, `3`, ... increment for every new value

And specify a pattern used to automatically select a certificate

Example: `{\"pattern\":\"https://www.contoso.com\",\"filter\":{\"ISSUER\":{\"CN\":\"certificate issuer name\", \"L\": \"certificate issuer location\", \"O\": \"certificate issuer org\", \"OU\": \"certificate issuer org unit\"}, \"SUBJECT\":{\"CN\":\"certificate subject name\", \"L\": \"certificate subject location\", \"O\": \"certificate subject org\", \"OU\": \"certificate subject org unit\"}}}`

More info on this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#autoselectcertificateforurls